# About forward/backward slashes in the url

Tags: url, directory, href, src

why for some urls u see the backward slash "/" for directories and for some you see the forward slash "\" for directories?  Is there a difference?

Comment: Do you have examples?

Answer (score 1):

Unix introduced `/` as the directory separator sometime around 1970. I don't know why this exactly character was chosen; the ancestor system Multics used `>`, but the designers of Unix had already used `>` together with `<` for redirection in the shell (see [Why is the root directory denoted by a `/` sign?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103471/why-is-the-root-directory-denoted-by-a-sign/103484#103484)).

[MS-DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) 2.0 introduced `\` as the directory separator in the early 1980s. The reason `/` was not used is that MS-DOS 1.0 (which did not support directories at all) was already using `/` to introduce command-line options. It took this usage of `/` from [CP/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M), which took it from [VMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS). You can read a more thorough explanation of why that choice was made [on Larry Osterman's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/24/432386.aspx) (MS-DOS even briefly had an option to change the option character to `-` and the directory separator to `/`, but it didn't stick).

`/` it is recognized by most programmer-level APIs (in all versions of DOS and Windows). So you can often, but not always get away with using `/` as a directory separator under Windows. A notable exception is that [you can't use `/` as a separator after the `\\?` prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) which (even in Windows 7) is the only way to specify a path using Unicode or containing more than 260 characters.

Some user interface elements support `/` as a directory separator under Windows, but not all. Some programs just pass filenames through to the underlying API, so they support `/` and `\` indifferently. In the command interpreter (in `command.com` or `cmd`), you can use `/` in many cases, but not always; this is partly dependent on the version of Windows (for example, `cd /windows` works in XP and 7 but did not in Windows 9x). The Explorer path entry box accepts `/` (at least from XP up; probably because it also accepts URLs). On the other hand, the standard file open dialog [rejects slashes](https://superuser.com/questions/441210/can-i-use-a-slash-in-the-windows-open-file-dialog).